# Python ggplot, how can I change the order of ticks

Tags: python, ggplot2

ggplot always plot the ticks or legends in alphabetical order. But I want to change it to something like `['today', 'yesterday', '1 week ago']` in that order.

In R ggplot, this is done by making the column a factor and `reorder` it. How can I do it in Python ggplot?